# VBA - Open a folder on Mac

Tags: vba, macos, applescript

I simply want to open a folder by VBA. I've tried the following code but it does nothing.

For Windows I know the following command is working fine

`Call Shell("explorer.exe " & filepath, vbNormalFocus)`

This is the code I am using...

```
Sub Open_Folder_On_Mac()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim RootFolder As String
Dim scriptstr As String

On Error Resume Next
RootFolder = MacScript("return (path to desktop folder) as String")

scriptstr = "do shell script ""open " & RootFolder & """"

MacScript (scriptstr)
End Sub
```

Can you help me, getting the code for simply opening a folder on a Mac? Thanks!

Comment: It appears the Mac equivalent of Windows Explorer is called the "Finder" app. So next step would be to research how to launch this "finder" app from VBA code. Surely there's a MacScript command for this.

Comment: Yes, but don't know how and do not find any information about it.

Comment: Found it! See linked post =)

Comment: Great! Thank you! I didn't find it ;-)

Comment: But to be honest...I do not know how to integrate this in VBA!?

Comment: Change the `scriptstr =` assignment to `scriptstr = "do shell script ""open " & RootFolder & """"`, then do `MacScript scriptstr` and remove the `MsgBox` part.

Comment: ```scriptstr = "do shell script ""open " & RootFolder & """"```
```MacScript (scriptstr)```

This does nothing!?

Comment: I've reopened your question - please [edit] your post with the updated code you're using; someone with a Mac will have an answer for that =)

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript does these kinds of things by telling a particular application to perform one or more of the commands exposed in the scripting dictionary (if any) provided by the application developer.  In the case of the **Finder** (which runs at all times), It would be:

```
tell application "Finder" to open theFolder
```

where *theFolder* is an `alias`, `file`, or `POSIX file` object, for example from:

```
set theFolder to (choose folder)
```

Note that the `open` shell utility is normally used to open files and applications.

---

Untested examples:

#### The older (deprecated) style:

• Note that this command may not work in a sandboxed application.

```
Dim ScriptString as String
Dim FolderPath as String

ScriptString = "tell application " & Chr(34) & "Finder" &  Chr(34) & " to open folder (path to desktop)"
-- or --
FolderPath = "Macintosh HD:Users:you:Path:To:Some:Folder:"
ScriptString =  "tell application " & Chr(34) & "Finder" &  Chr(34) & " to open folder " & FolderPath

MacScript(ScriptString)
```

#### The newer (2016+) style:

• Create a script using the **Script Editor** that contains the handlers (subroutines) you want to call, for example:

```
on openFolder(folderPath)
    tell application "Finder" to open folder folderPath
end openFolder
```

• Place the script in your user's `~/Library/Application Scripts/[bundle id]` folder, where [bundle id] is the bundle identifier of the application using the script.

• The new command is in the form `AppleScriptTask("script file name.scpt", "handler name", "handler argument")`, for example:

```
Dim FolderPath as String

FolderPath = "Macintosh HD:Users:you:Path:To:Some:Folder:"
AppleScriptTask("MyScript.scpt", "openFolder", FolderPath)
```

See [Run an AppleScript with VB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/applescripttask).

Comment: How does the code look like referring to my code-example above? I am a bit lost.

Comment: I don't have VBA, but it looks like it would be something like `MacScript("tell application "Finder" to open (path to desktop folder)")` - you would also need to add whatever escapes for those quotes in the script string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, but AppleScript is not really userfriendly. One has to store the script on his computer in order to use it. I am looking for another solution.

Comment: If the application is sandboxed, Apple's requirements limit your options for using third party scripts - basically the user has to be involved in setting up the scripts.